# POST request with string parameters and array

Tags: arrays, swift, post, parameters, request

I want to make a POST request and pass some parameters.
The parameters I want to pass is:

```
- Item : String
- Length : String
- Names : String Array
- Age : String
```

Today I´m doing this

```
var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "URL")!
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = // parameters here?
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
               (response, data, error) in
               println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

Can anyone provide help of how to pass the above parameters in my request? I´m not quite sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that the `HTTPBody` expect a `NSData` object, so you can create  Dictionary with the data you need as @dsk explain in this answer and then convert it to JSON to pass as parameters using the `dataWithJSONObject` function, like in the following way:

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

var values: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
values["item"] = "value"
values["length"] = "value"
values["names"] = ["value1", "value2"]
values["age"] = "value"

request.HTTPBody = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(values, options: [])
```

Nevertheless I strongly recommend you use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) to handle all the networking process more easily.

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable for your parameters:

```
var params: [String: AnyObject] = [:]
params["item"] = "YOUR_STRING"
params["length"] = "YOUR_STRING"
params["names"] = ["YOUR_STRING1", "YOUR_STRING2"]
params["age"] = "YOUR_STRING"
```

Assuming the `POST` is a JSON request, add them to the `HTTPBody` as such:

```
request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: [])
```